# how to make it clear to the browsers that "you can save this fields"

Tags: gwt, twitter-bootstrap, uibinder, gwt-bootstrap

I have two GWT Bootstrap form fields Email and password

```java
<b:WellForm  height="400px" ui:field="loginPanel">
    <g:VerticalPanel horizontalAlignment="ALIGN_CENTER"
                            width="100%">
        <b:FormLabel ui:field="emailErrorLabel" visible="false">
            <font color="red">
                <i>&nbsp;Please enter your login name</i>
            </font>
        </b:FormLabel>
        <b:TextBox  alternateSize="LARGE" b:id="Email"
            ui:field="Email" placeholder="E-mail"  width="335px"
            height="30px" />
    </g:VerticalPanel>
```

and i want browser to tell to store the email addresses and password entered and prompt remember password .how can i do this in gwt bootstrap. please help

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you rephrase?

Comment: @enrybo i have a login page. And on Login i want browser to ask weather password should be stored

Answer (score 0):

With HTML you have to use `autocomplete='on'`. By the way it is good practice to use `autocomplete='off'` on login and password input fields in case of a CSRF attack.

You'll have to do something like

```
TextBox box;
box.getElement().setPropertyString("autocomplete", "on")
```